# error while using locallydb in ari-client node.js

Tags: node.js

_http_outgoing.js:299
    value = value.replace(/[\r\n]+[ \t]*/g, '');
                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at storeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:299:19)
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage._storeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:225:9)
    at ClientRequest._implicitHeader (_http_client.js:184:8)
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:513:10)
    at createRequest (/root/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/ari-client/node_modules/swagger-client/node_modules/shred/lib/shred/request.js:532:16)
    at new Request (/root/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/ari-client/node_modules/swagger-client/node_modules/shred/lib/shred/request.js:79:3)
    at Object.Shred.request (/root/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/ari-client/node_modules/swagger-client/node_modules/shred/lib/shred.js:47:12)
    at ShredHttpClient.execute (/root/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/ari-client/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/swagger.js:1314:21)
    at SwaggerHttp.execute (/root/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/ari-client/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/swagger.js:1134:34)
    at new SwaggerRequest (/root/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/ari-client/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/swagger.js:1099:27)

Comment: I'm having the same error. Wish this was more flushed out.